# some problems parsing xml from webservice with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am having issues with parsing the xml response got from the service at http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Lookup

My code for the main is the one [up here](http://pastebin.com/XjYxBSxE), toghether with annotated beans that build up the xml.

I'd like to 'debug' what's going on in the `JAXBContext`, so that I can see what I messed up in the annotated beans. The only thing I found it is possible is to register an `EventHandler` like this:

```
unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new javax.xml.bind.helpers.DefaultValidationEventHandler());
```

that prints errors like these:

```
uri http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/KeywordSearch?QueryString=galway&MaxHits=5
DefaultValidationEventHandler: [ERROR]: unexpected element (uri:"http://lookup.dbpedia.org/", local:"Result"). Expected elements are <{}Result> 
     Location: line 3
```

It seems there is an unexpected element Result, but I can't manage to fix it. 
Can someone guide me in understanding the JAXB errors more in depth? I really can't figure out what the errors really mean (as I already have set up `namespace = "http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Lookup"` in the `ArrayOfResult` class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the namespace information specified on ArrayOfResult but not on Result:

```
package it.cybion.dbpedia.textsearch.rest.response;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Result", namespace="http://lookup.dbpedia.org/")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Result {
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought. The syntax {}Result is confusing, but if you know that the {} should contain the namespace (which it technically does even now of course) the error becomes more clear. I hope.

Comment: If this answered your question please consider marking it as the accepted answer.  For more information on JAXB and namespaces, you can refer to:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: thank you, this was absolutely not trivial for me! now i just have to figure out how to organise package level annotations to clean up my classes' code!